# How to remove unavailable app from the app list after phone restore

Tags: windows-10-mobile, apps, backup, lumia-950-xl

I have changed my Windows phone recently. When setting up the new phone I performed restore from my backup. This installs all apps you had installed on the previous phone. The problem comes with apps that are not available in Store any more. Those apps keep hanging the app list with greyed icon and label "pending".

Is there a way how to remove such apps from app list? Uninstall menu item is disabled for all such apps when you tap and hold their icon.

My system version is 1607, phone is Lumia 950 XL.

Comment: If you go to the Store > Downloads and Updates are you able to cancel the downloads there?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not see such apps listed there...

Comment: What happens when you click on the app? Does it take you the store page? Was there any option to cancel the download there?

Comment: @KolappanNathan Thanks, that helped! When I tap the disabled app icon, it takes me to the store page where I have an option to install the app (and  I can uninstall it afterwards). I do not know why but I only tried tap-and-hold on an app icon previously... If you post your comment as an answers, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform the following steps:

1. Tap on the app in the Apps list.
2. It will open the corresponding store page.
3. From there you can install and uninstall the app or cancel the download(if any) in store.